# How to fit the image in fieldset Html

Tags: html, image, fieldset

I want to fit the image inside the fieldset.
here is code.

```
<fieldset>
<legend>abcas</legend>
    <img src="red.PNG"  />
</fieldset>
```

upper side of fieldset is empty.Image can not fit inside it, how can i fit it.
If I remove the legend then it fit in it.

Comment: seems to be fitting fine on my side, check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W6hX9/ .... Maybe create one of your own displaying the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on Fiddle and it works fine, it does fit.

http://jsfiddle.net/tHWz8/

```
<fieldset>
<legend>abcas</legend>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"  />
</fieldset>
```